# Superfish Menu: looking for specific css value

Tags: theming, navigation

Using Drupal 7.19 and [Superfish](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish) 7.x-1.8

I was able to override most of the CSS and we are working towards a menu that we would like. However, I would like the parent menu item that is looked at to show a certain color. But it goes transparent once the mouse if off if it is unactive.

I am looking to make the unactive parentmenu item go a certain color if the child is hovered. I can't find the id/class via firebug, but am still looking.

If you look at the image provided, we want "Nuestro Institución" to show `#fec24a` (yellow) when it is expanded and unactive.

The site is in Spanish and these are the institutional colours.

I had an image attached, but I can't post it as a new user, so I will include the site I am working on.

Please remember that it is a work in progress.

http://devel.idl.org.pe/

Answer (score 0):

The HTML element for "Our Institution" is:

```
<li id="menu-679-1" class="middle even sf-item-2 sf-depth-1 sf-total-children-5 sf-parent-children-0 sf-single-children-5 menuparent"><a href="/content/nosotros" title="" class="sf-depth-1  menuparent">Nuestro Institución</a>
```

You want the :hover value of this li item when you're on a child item. This is:

```
<li id="menu-679-1" class="middle even sf-item-2 sf-depth-1 sf-total-children-5 sf-parent-children-0 sf-single-children-5 menuparent sfHover"><a href="/content/nosotros" title="" class="sf-depth-1  menuparent">Nuestro Institución</a>
```

In my opinion this always gets ugly in CSS, for just that 1 menu item you could do (depending on your rules already in CSS):

`#menu-679-1.sfHover {background-color: yellow;}`

or if that doesnt work:

```
#menu-679-1.middle.even.sf-item-2.sf-depth-1.sf-total-children-5.sf-parent-children-0.sf-single-children-5.menuparent.sfHover { background-color: yellow; }
```

I would just write 1 css class per menu ID you want to target. If you use LESS CSS preprocessor you can use a small template to apply the hover color. You might be able to use a descendant selector but I always run in problems selecting all child `<li>`s when I do that ....

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you should start by chosing a style from the superfish block administration and see if the background changes for hovered  menu parent elements. (It should - only the default style - that you are using now has no background). If it is, copy the stylesheet to a new one (let's say newstyle.css) and rename(use a find/replace all tool) all occurances of old stylesheet name in the classes names with the "newstyle". Then edit the colors or other formatting as you like in the new stylesheet.

If not, which is again your case, you should remove or edit the .sf-menu classes from yoour sites/devel.idl.org.pe/themes/corolla/css/navigation.css

the background for your main parent elements is given in the corrola navigation stylesheet  by :

```
.sf-menu li.sfHover
```

and by(line42) :

```
.sf-menu.sf-style-space-orange li.sfHover
```

in the orange-space.css(as an example) file - that you should have it in the sites/all/libraries/superfish/style

Also you should look in sites/devel.idl.org.pe/themes/footheme/css/footheme.css and i guess the generated css of footheme sites/devel.idl.org.pe/files/color/footheme-9c3b33ed/colors.css for conflicts on the lines that start with #menu-bar